# regex replace all leading and trailing non-alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the correct regex for superTrim() to satisfy the description and pass the test:

```
// removes all leading and trailing whitespace, newlines, escaped whitespace,
//    escaped punctuation, punctuation, special characters, etc
//    - EVERYTHING leading and trailing that is not alphanumeric.
const superTrim = (src: string) => src.replace(/<-- correct regex here --> /gm, "").trim();


if (import.meta.vitest) {
  const { describe, expect, it, test } = await import("vitest");

  test("superTrim", () => {
    expect(superTrim("John Smith")).toBe("John Smith");
    expect(superTrim("Bobby Lee\\n \\n,  ")).toBe("Bobby Lee");
    expect(superTrim("Sally Mae\n \n,  ")).toBe("Sally Mae");
    expect(superTrim("JCP Dept. Stores\\nAttn: Marketing\n , '\n '"))
      .toBe("JCP Dept. Stores\\nAttn: Marketing");
  });
}
```

I did find some similar but different enough existing questions that I think a new question is warranted. I could iterate over the string identifying markers to return a slice but this seems to be regex solution.

Comment: Why should `\\n` be removed? The `n` is alpha and thus makes the literal backslash non-trailing

Comment: Because I want trailing \\n removed. Explaining the entire system including upstream data is not needed for this question. / / was meant to be a placeholder. of course Im not replacing every  ' '.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear... `\\n` is not a newline (in case you thought it was). It is in fact a literal backslash followed by a literal `"n"`. Since a literal `"n"` is alpha-numeric, why should you expect it to be removed from the end of a string? https://jsfiddle.net/1cq2omtf/ for clarity

Comment: The question is  trim all leading and trailing that is not alphanumerical and provided several cases with the question. This seems to have ruffled your feathers, but I do not think there is ambiguity.  We can have a semantic discussion of whether or not and escaped line-break char constitutes a newline in this context elsewhere.

The escaped line-breaks are also a sticky point with all my prev efforts. The Bobby Lee case fails all the time - hence why Im asking here.

Comment: I agree with @Phil: The expected result is unreasonable given the requirements. `"\\n"` means a string that contains two *literal* characters, i.e. backslash and the alphanumeric `n`, whereas `"\n"` means a string that contains one "new line" character. That being said, `"Bobby Lee\\n \\n,  "` results in these *literal* characters: `Bobby Lee\n \n,  `. Is that clear?

Comment: `/^(\\+n|[^0-9a-zA-Z])*(.*?)([^0-9a-zA-Z]|\\+n)*$/` https://regex101.com/r/WV2RE6/1

Comment: @Arleigh Hix NICE! I was thinking of this backward but capturing the noise to replace by defining what I wanted. Your solution of just capturing what I want is exactly what is needed.  Confirmed it works for the provided cases and a few others too. Can you make it an answer and Ill accept it?

Comment: @InSync & Phil - is the selected answer clear? Just because you don't understand something doesn't mean the other person doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to capture and return the part you want:

```js
// returns EVERYTHING bounded by the first and last non-escaped, alphanumeric.
const getLean = (src) => src.match(/^(\\+[0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z])*(.*?)([^0-9a-zA-Z]|\\+[0-9a-zA-Z])*$/)[2];

console.log(getLean("John Smith") === "John Smith")
console.log(getLean("Bobby Lee\\n \\n,  ") === "Bobby Lee")
console.log(getLean("Sally Mae\n \n,  ") === "Sally Mae")
console.log(getLean(" %*&-->JCP Dept. Stores\\nAttn: Marketing\n , '\n '") === "JCP Dept. Stores\\nAttn: Marketing");
console.log(getLean("\nBobby Lee\\n \\c\t,  ") === "Bobby Lee")
```

### Regex capturing groups:

1. `^(\\+[0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z])*`
   At the beginning of the string matches EITHER a literal `\` one or more times followed by a single alphanumeric, OR any single non-alphanumeric, zero or more times as many times as possible (greedy).
2. `(.*?)` *the piece you seek*
   Anything and everything, left in the middle (non-greedy).
3. `([^0-9a-zA-Z]|\\+[0-9a-zA-Z])*$`
   Same as 1, but anchored at the end of the string with the `|`(OR) reversed just for symmetry

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you for addressing the actual question and not arguing over the bigger picture which is not in scope of the question or assuming I just don't get something. Also added a fuzzer in my unit tests and have not surfaced an edge case.

Comment: for others needing the same, I did tweak and to solve for some edges:

const superTrim = (str: string) =>
  str === "" || str.match(/^\s*$/) || str.match(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)
    ? "" : str.replace(/^(\\+[rtn\f\v]|[^0-9a-zA-Z])*(.*?)([^0-9a-zA-Z]|\\+[rtn\f\v])*$/, "$2");

Answer (score -2):

You can use this regularity to fulfill your requirements：`(^[\W\\n]*)|([\W\\n]*$)`

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer Autumn but it fails the test cases. Arleigh solved it above. Sorry you answer got voted down before I even saw it. Someone seems pretty aggressive with it. No idea why my question has two down votes.

Comment: This regularity itself can satisfy the tests you listed，I tested it on regex101 and didn't use js code to test it, so I didn't list the specific js code。
You can check it out here：https://regex101.com/r/YxRoTE/1

Comment: I am also very strange about the negative vote. I have just signed up for this website, and I don't know the rules here, but he looks terrible. I just try to help others and answer some questions, and I will receive inexplicable opposition. It seems that people who are often active in this website can send out negative votes at will without going through their brains. I answered a question yesterday, and the answer is valid. It's too bad for a person to directly give a no vote and close the question because of the way I answered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).